# Flutter: Programatically perform a button click

Tags: flutter, dart, button, simulation, keypress

How can you programatically perform a button click in Flutter? I basically want to bind a number of buttons to keys on the keyboard, the most important part is that after a key is pressed the corresponding button the visual state of the button is triggered to inform the user which button was pressed.

I am aware you can invoke the `onTap` function, but that by itself doesn't update the visual state of button. Is there a way to simulate this kind of behavior, I tried to look into `MaterialStateController` but doesn't feel like it's the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that _InkWellResponseState (internal-) classes have a function called `simulateTap`. The function is bound against ActivateIntent and by default this intend is fired whenever the user presses `Enter` or `Space`

```
class SimActivateIntent extends ActivateIntent {
  const SimActivateIntent (this.model);
  final FocusNode model;
}

class SimActivateAction extends Action<SimActivateIntent> {
  SimActivateAction ();
  @override
  void invoke(covariant SimActivateIntentintent) {
    Actions.maybeInvoke(intent.model.context!, const ActivateIntent());
  }
}
```

With the intends listed above one can invoke the ActivateIntent on a specific object and simulate a button press. They can bound into the application using `Shortcuts` & `Actions` classes.

```
Map<ShortcutActivator, Intent> get defaultShortcuts {
    return <ShortcutActivator, Intent>{
       const SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace):
          SimActivateIntent(digitBackspace),
    }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context)
{
    return Shortcuts(
      shortcuts: defaultShortcuts,
      child: Actions(
      actions: <Type, Action<Intent>>{
        SimActivateIntent: SimActivateAction(),
      },
      child: ...
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say that you could use the `MaterialStateController` to simulate that the button has been pressed.

This can be done by updating the state controller in some good enough fashion of your choice. Something like this perhaps:

[image]

Non-optimized code for this (you will bind to keys on the keyboard instead):

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    button2StatesController.update(MaterialState.pressed, true);
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    button2StatesController.update(MaterialState.pressed, false);
  },
  child: const Text('Button 1'),
),
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  statesController: button2StatesController,
  child: const Text('Button 2'),
)
```

You cannot simulate the InkWell effect (as far as I know) without more intervention. Like creating your own button with your own inkwell animations etc...

Comment: Not too fond of this because with the states controller there is a visual disparity between the two buttons that I want to avoid, and with the states controller you'd basically have manually time press/release which can differ from origional button implementation.

Comment: I understand, unfortunately I dont think you can do it without designing your own widget. And you cannot compare it to the original timing because that can also depend on how fast a user release the button upon s press.

Comment: The press coordinates in the Inkwell used by the button cannot be overridden or injected. So you have to design this yourself with your own widget.

Comment: One could also argue that there should be a disparity because the user isn't hitting the button.. but that is opinionated:)

Comment: That's definitely true, what I was actually thinking is when the button has focus and user pressed enter it basically does the whole press/release animation by itself, so was just thinking isn't it possible to send an "enter" key event to the widget directly.